# Create a loading window in PyQt4

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a program that graphs data using an embedded `matplotlib` plot and adds helpful visualizations. The problem is `matplotlib` can be very slow when these visualizations are heavy, to the point where the main window hangs. I can't add these graphics in a different thread or process because PyQt forbids updating the main window from anywhere but the main thread (for good reason), so instead I would like to have another window with basically a perpetual progress bar that I can kill when the graphing is done:

```
# Creates a new window with an endless progress bar
class LoadingWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoadingWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)

        main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Graphing now. Please wait...", self))
        progress = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
        progress.setMinimum(0)
        progress.setMaximum(0)
        layout.addWidget(progress)

        main_widget.setLayout(layout)
        main_widget.setFocus()
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
        self.show()
```

... but when I create an instance of this class the loading bar doesn't show up and both windows hang. Is there a way to make this window come up in a new thread or process? Or is there a better way to fix this problem in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. It's not a total fix but I had to go back through to where the visualizations are being added and periodically call this function:

```
QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
```

This let my UI update every once in a while so that the window at least didn't hang. I also thought it best to disable the main window so that the user can't mess things up while the graphs are being generated, and I added the Loading Window from my original post so that the user knows whats happening.